# I am working on Entity Framework Core 6.0.10 migrations with Azure Devops process

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure-devops, entity-framework-core

While I am trying to update a Postgresql database with `dotnet ef` migrations add and update command at first time the database is updated but at the second time I get an error:

> Table 'name' already exists

I tried these things:

1. Dotnet ef database update
2. Bundling process
3. Generating SQL scripts and updating etc

But all these options didn't incrementally update the database.

Then while migrating I deleted the database and deployed it, this worked out. But for me this is not the best case.

Is there any approach from devops prospective to incrementally create migrations and update database?

Comment: 2 possibilities that come to mind: 1) the meta data table is not properly linking to the migration you used (sometimes the type name it saves is wrong in some way, maybe you changed the namespace for example). 2) make sure you're issuing the right commands. for each new version of the DB, you want to first add a new migration and then update the DB with it (two steps). depending how and where you are applying these commands, the syntax can vary a fair bit.

Comment: I have followed the same approach. First to add new migration and then update the DB. Can you suggest me how to add initial migration and next migrations for incremental process

Comment: if you follow these rough steps: Enable-Migrations (works), Add-Migration <initial> (works), Update-Database (works), Add-Migration <second> (works), Update-Database (fails, tries to do first migration again). If that's what happens, then it's probably the typename in the metadata table is not matching the migration type name. This can be from a namespace problem, but can also I think be from using sdk csproj. You might need the `EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention` property to be set to true. (Although I might expect the first migration to also fail in that case).

Comment: another thing to note is that if you are using ef6 and have both ef6 and efcore installed, you will need to prefix your commands with something like EntityFramework6\Add-Migration otherwise it will possibly choose Core instead. I think it would tell you about this though. (note I can't remember for 100% sure what the prefix actually is.)

Comment: Thanks @DaveCousineau. From azure devops we were not keeping track of migration folder but now we are doing that and it is working.